# How to make selected drop down option stay selected after submit

Tags: php

I am trying to make the select box sticky that is located in the first `foreach` loop:

I believe there should be an `if` statement located inside the `<option>` tag like below:

```
if($selectedMake==$key){ 
  echo selected='selected';
}

echo "<option im not sure how to properly enter it in here?>$key</option>"
```

---

// Start of code below:

```
$selectedMake = $_POST['make'];
$cars = array(
    'Toyota'=>array(
        'Corolla'=>array(
            'image'=>'corolla.png',
            'colour'=>'blue',
            'transmission'=>'manual',
            'doors'=>'2'
            ),
        'Highlander'=>array(
            'image'=>'highlander.png',
            'colour'=>'silver',
            'transmission'=>'auto',
            'doors'=>'4'
            ),
        ),

    'Mazda'=>array(
        'RX7'=>array(

            'colour'=>'blue',
            'transmission'=>'manual',
            'doors'=>'2'
            ),
        'MX-5'=>array(
            'colour'=>'red',
            'transmission'=>'manual',
            'doors'=>'2'
            )
        )


    );
echo '<form method="post" action="cars.php">';
echo '<select name="make">';
foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {

    echo "<option>$key</option>"; // This option tag needs to be made sticky

}

echo '</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$selectedMake = $_POST['make'];

echo "<h1>$selectedMake</h1>";
foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
    if ($selectedMake == $key) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            echo "<b>$key</b> <br>";
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'image') {

                echo '<img src="imgs/'.$value.'" width="150px">';
            } else {
                echo "<li>$key: $value</li>";
            }

        }
    echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
} else {
echo "Not clicked";
}



echo '<pre>',print_r($cars),'</pre>';

 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"sticky"*?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained that. When you select an option from the drop down menu and you click submit, when it reloads the page it should stay at the option you selected.

Comment: Why `echo` great chunks of static HTML?

Comment: Good point Phil, I have now amended my local file. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by sticky, you mean selected if it matches the value you have then:

```
echo "<option".($selectedMake==$key ? " selected" : "").">$key</option>"
```

Comment: Watch the formatting there. This will produce `<optionselected>`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I know what you mean. You want something like this...

```
<select name="make">
<?php
foreach (array_keys($cars) as $key) :
$selected = $key === $selectedMake ? ' selected' : '';
?>
    <option<?= $selected ?>><?= htmlspecialchars($key) ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Phil, I didn't try yours as I went for the option that RMK provided. Appreciated though :)

Comment: I would consider putting the static HTML outside of the PHP script like Phil did though since it's generally better practice.